# I cant click on image url in Django

Tags: html, django, django-templates

So I wanted to have this logo in the blog app, which was going to be part of each page, so users can always click on it, and ideally, when they click on it, it shall lead them to a page with articles. So this the code that I written in base file, but for some reason its not clickable:
base.html

```
{%  load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Articles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}" >
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "wrapper">
        <h1><a href = "{% url 'articles:list' %}"> </a><img src="{% static 'article.png' %}"/> </h1>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logo image should be into anchor:

```
<h1>
    <a href = "{% url 'articles:list' %}" title="????">
        <img src="{% static 'article.png' %}" alt="????" />
    </a>
</h1>
```

please don't forget `alt` for image and `title` for anchor, to made your page better for peoples with "barriers"

Comment: It worked, it was kind of logical when you look at it. Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Please keep image src inside your anchor tag

```
 {%  load static %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Articles</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "wrapper">
            <h1><a href = "{% url 'articles:list' %}"> <img src="{% static 'article.png' %}"/></a> </h1>
<!--changes here-->
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yess, that was it. Thanks!!